# How to use Shortcuts on my iPhone to call in to conferences?

Tags: iphone, ios, call, shortcuts-app

I have to attend a lot of conference meetings and each of these meetings uses their own conference id or conference number. Usually I call a number and wait for the automated voice to enter the conference number. And then I press a number of `#` to join the call.

Of course, I know, I can call the number including the conference id to join the meeting. Therefore I call `202-456-1111,,30030011###` and I am logged in the conference service under 202-456-1111 with the conference id 30030011.

But I hate to type this in all the time and was looking for a shortcut. I go with this

1. Ask for Input (Input Type = Number)
2. Text: `202456111,,{Ask for Input}###`
3. Call

But it only calls the number ignoring everything else including the colons. But in the end the output of the call operation is the expected full number including the colons and hashpounds.

How to change the script to successful be asked for the conference number and perform the call as expected?

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar that works for me.  In my case, there's an optional attendee ID as well.  The conference number I'm showing here is 1-555-555-5555

1. Ask "Meeting access code" (Input type = Number)
2. Set variable {ConfNum} to {Provided Input}
3. Ask Attendee ID (Input type = Number, default = 0)
4. If Provided Input is 0
5. Text 1555-555-5555,,{ConfNum}#,#
6. Otherwise
7. Text 1555-555-5555,,{ConfNum}#,{Provided Input}#
8. End If
9. Call {If Result}

Also note that if you use a semicolon (`;`) instead of a comma (`,`) for the pause, it will wait until you press a button to dial the remaining string.